# Convert array of records to JSON in PostgreSQL without array_to_json

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql-10

SQL in PostgreSQL:

```
create table test.tt (text_text text[]);
insert into test.tt values('{111,4,101803,5}');
```

It is an `array text[]`. I want convert it to `json` like this:

```
{111:44,101803:5} as json
```

I tried `array_to_json`, but it can't.

Comment: First of all {"111":"44","101803":"5"} this is not a array format in JSON. It may be like ["111":"44","101803":"5"].

Comment: There is no direct way to convert this array to JSON as you want.. you have to manually write function to convert it and store in db again...

Comment: Did you try row_to_json?

Comment: function row_to_json can not conver array to json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yyou can use `json_object()` to convert that to a JSON:

```
select json_object(text_text)
from test.tt;
```

Note that this will only work if all values have an even number of elements!

The above returns

```
json_object                  
-----------------------------
{"111" : "4", "101803" : "5"}
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/STYJP65628